# Proper use 'hidden' attribute in html tag

Tags: html, css

I've run into a problem and hope someone here can enlighten me:

```
<div class="myclass" hidden></>
```

When running locally, this div is not displayed. This is correct, right? But if I add the hidden attribute to the class tag, ie:

```
<div class="myclass hidden"></>
```

The div is displayed. This is what should happen.

But when I deploy the 'correct' code to our test environment, the div still displays, but it does not if I add the 'hidden' attribute to the class tag. I've manually edited the html in Chrome and can duplicate the behavior. I don't understand why this is. Can someone help me out here?
Thanks

Comment: The behavior is unexpected because each closing tag needs the tag name, i.e. `</div>`. The second tag is more correct though, because `hidden` is not a known keyword in HTML and should be used as a class name instead, like in the second example.

Comment: @symlink _“`hidden` is not a known keyword in HTML and should be used as a class name instead”_ — [`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) is a global HTML attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hidden isn't a class name, its a attribute. Unless you have a class called "hidden" in your .css code, then `<div class="myclass hidden"></>` will never work. Think of `hidden` as a action that does something. Another example is `disabled` this is an action that disables the element. Hidden hides an element. Which is why `<div class="myclass" hidden></>` works and is the correct way to use `hidden`. Hopefully that's a good explanation.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense to me. By the way, those close tags should be </div>. A typo on my part.

Comment: Glad I could help in a way that makes sense and logical.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `<div class="myclass" hidden>` you are using a global HTML attribute, which will make browsers won't render the element.

On the other case `<div class="myclass hidden">` you are adding a class named `hidden` to your element, which can or not be associated to whatever custom style you want to add to it, but will not generate any "default" style to it whatsoever.

Comment: Technically, it doesn't add `display: none` to the element. Add the attribute and check the styles; you will find no (extra) mention of the `display` CSS property. It takes the element out of the flow, just like `display: none`, but is distinct.

Comment: @HereticMonkey but if you check on Chrome Dev Tools, for instance, you will find `display: none;` in the `div[Attributes Style]`. It is not adding directly to the element, but is somehow adding to it. No?

Comment: But anyways, I've update my answer to avoid any missunderstanding.

Comment: Chrome may do that, but, for instance, Edge does not, nor does Firefox. It's not part of the standard, let's just say that. Thanks for the update.

Comment: @HereticMonkey oh, ok! Thank you for the correction! Every day you learn something new. :)

Answer (score 0):

The [hidden tag attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_hidden.asp) isn't compatible with all browser versions, as you can see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_hidden.asp):

```
 Browser Support (from which version is available):
 Chrome: 6.0
 Firefox: 4.0
 Safari: 5.1
 Opera: 11.1
 Internet Explorer / Edge: 11.0
```

To properly hidden a tag, use this:

```
<div class="myclass hidden">...</div>

<style>
    .hidden { visibility:hidden; display:none; }
</style>
```

`display:none` hides the tag completely (you can still interact with it through the DOM).

With `visibility:hidden` the tag isn't visible, but it occupies its space on the page.

Comment: Why would you add both? `visibility: hidden` has no effect if the element is taken out of the flow...

Comment: Because of browser compatibility and different behavior

Comment: I noticed that in the past different browsers handle differently these tags.

Comment: I mean, it doesn't *hurt* per se, except that it changes two properties rather than one... Then again, this question is about the difference between the `hidden` attribute and putting the word `hidden` in the class attribute, so this answer doesn't exactly answer that.